# How to update Django model fields in MySQL database

Tags: python, django, django-models, field, mysql-python

I created a model for posts in Django and I'm trying to update one of the fields in the database (MySQL).
I have the following block of code:
model.py

```
class Post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    preamble = models.CharField()
    body = models.TextField ()
createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

I want to add another field called author `author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE`
Also, I want to change the name of one of the fields from `preamble` to `introduction`

Whenever I run the command `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`, I get an error which terminates the migration process. it's telling me that the field `preamble` which I have in my database is not recognized. Is it possible to update `preamble` to `introduction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ensure you have a migration of the initial state of your app, before any modifications.
- Rename the `preamble` field to `introduction` in your model, making no other changes.
- Run `makemigrations`. It should ask you whether it was a rename.
- Add the `author` foreign key.
- Run `makemigrations`. It should ask you for a default for the user field if it's not nullable; `1` should hopefully refer to the first user created in your system.
- Run `migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work:

1. delete the SQLite database and also migrations directory
2. change the model
3. then run the migrate command